# Hibernate does not create tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have sample maven project with support of Hibernate. Problem is: Hibernate  doesn't create tables in database. Answers in similar questions on stack overflow suggests set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to "create", but it doesn't work.

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-..">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_test</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="Person"></mapping>
    </session_factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = Long.MIN_VALUE;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column
private Long id;

@Column
private String firstName;

//getters/setters etc.
```

The execution stops on next lines:

```
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Sep 06, 2016 10:56:57 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Sep 06, 2016 10:56:57 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@3f9f7f6'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: does your DB already contains tables? if it does then is it printing drop table statements in log?

Comment: No, there is no tables in db, and there is no logs such as "drop" or "create" etc.

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: @BishalPaudel, sorry, I can't remember how I solved this problem. During the work I include "persistance" to project, and with persistance all start works fine, I guess...